# react-native error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@react-navigation\routers\src\index.tsx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I ran the project.  ***npx react-native run-android***
Why did this error occur?
I need guidance to solve this problem.

[image: Error Image]

```
Looking for JS files in
   D:\React native projects\appOne

Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@react-navigation\routers\src\index.tsx: Unexpected token (9:12)

   7 | export { default as StackRouter, StackActions } from './StackRouter';
   8 |
>  9 | export type {
     |             ^
  10 |   StackActionHelpers,
  11 |   StackActionType,
  12 |   StackRouterOptions,
    at Object.raise (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:6387:17)
    at Object.unexpected (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:7704:16)
    at Object.parseIdentifierName (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9592:18)
    at Object.parseIdentifier (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:9570:23)
    at Object.tsParseTypeAliasDeclaration (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:4793:20)
    at Object.tsParseDeclaration (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5111:23)
    at Object.tsTryParseExportDeclaration (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5020:17)
    at Object.parseExportDeclaration (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5497:26)
    at Object.maybeParseExportDeclaration (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11038:31)
    at Object.parseExport (D:\React native projects\appOne\node_modules\@babel\core\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:10967:29)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░ 30.9% (266/496), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2020:19:52:38 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

Comment: What version of `@babel/core` and `@babel/runtime` are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type-only` `imports` and `exports` is a new feature in `TypeScript 3.8`. Babel added support type-only imports/exports through this [merge request](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11171) and is available from version `7.9.0`

Update your babel version as shown below:

```
 "devDependencies": {
         "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
         "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
         //other dev dependencies
    }
```

You might need to delete `node_modules`, reinstall and clear cache.

Answer (score -1):

It is an Typescript error...

try :
**yarn add --dev typescript**

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#im-getting-syntaxerror-in-react-navigationxxxxxxtsx-or-syntaxerror-xxxreact-navigationxxxxxxtsx-unexpected-token

Answer (score -1):

You need to install `babel/core` and `babel/runtime` for it to work. Here is the code for that:

```
npm i @babel/core @babel/runtime typescript -d
```